# При использовании umap для визуализации данных возникает ошибка

Tags: python, pandas, big-data, sklearn

Программа из примера, но тем не менее у меня она не работает. Программа должна визуализировать данные с использованием библиотеки umap-learn.

```
import umap
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE


data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\ASUS\\Desktop\\zoo.csv') # Данные с животными
data.dropna(inplace=True) # Удалим NaN значения
D = data.drop(['class_type', 'animal_name'], axis=1) # Отбросим нечисловые столбцы

scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
D = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(D), columns=D.columns)

T = TSNE(n_components=2, perplexity=50, random_state=123)
TSNE_features = T.fit_transform(D)

DATA = D.copy()
DATA['x'] = TSNE_features[:, 0]
DATA['y'] = TSNE_features[:, 1]

scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
D = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(D), columns=D.columns)

n_n = (5, 25, 50)  # n_neighbors
m_d = (0.1, 0.6)  # min_dist

um = dict()
for i in range(len(n_n)):
    for j in range(len(m_d)):
        um[(n_n[i], m_d[j])] = (umap.UMAP(n_neighbors=n_n[i], min_dist=m_d[j], random_state=123).fit_transform(DATA))
```

Текст ошибки

```
C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\pr2\venv\lib\site-packages\umap\umap_.py:1943: UserWarning: n_jobs value -1 overridden to 1 by setting random_state. Use no seed for parallelism.
  warn(f"n_jobs value {self.n_jobs} overridden to 1 by setting random_state. Use no seed for parallelism.")
```

Через гугл ошибки не смог найти.
В итоге должно получится примерно это:
[image: Визуализация данных с помощью umap]

Попытался добавить строчку `umap.numerical_n_jobs = 1` но не помогло.

Comment: ну попробуйте из `(umap.UMAP(n_neighbors=n_n[i], min_dist=m_d[j], random_state=123)` убрать `random_state=123` вообще. об этом буквально написано в тексте ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка, которую вы видите, связана с параметром n_jobs в библиотеке
UMAP. Ошибка говорит о том, что параметр n_jobs был установлен в -1,
но был переопределен на значение 1 из-за установки параметра
random_state.

Установка n_jobs в -1 обычно означает использование всех доступных
ядер процессора для параллельных вычислений. Однако, похоже, в этой
ситуации библиотека UMAP переопределяет n_jobs на 1, так как указан
параметр random_state.

Чтобы устранить эту ошибку, вы можете явно указать значение параметра
n_jobs, которое вам нужно, вместо использования значения -1. Например,
чтобы использовать все доступные ядра процессора, укажите n_jobs=-1 в
конструкторе класса umap.UMAP.

Пример:

```
um = dict()
for i in range(len(n_n)):
    for j in range(len(m_d)):
        um[(n_n[i], m_d[j])] = (umap.UMAP(n_neighbors=n_n[i], min_dist=m_d[j], random_state=123, n_jobs=-1).fit_transform(DATA))
```

Это позволит библиотеке UMAP использовать все доступные ядра
процессора для параллельных вычислений, если они доступны на вашей
системе, и должно решить проблему с этой ошибкой.